# How to input any Numerical type using input output in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, console

In haskell to input a String we use getLine and to input a character we use getChar but what is used to input any integer or float?

I search a lot and I found but it also use getLine for integer.
[This is the link where I found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42214305/how-to-input-an-integer-in-haskell-input-in-console)

It really works as I used this in my code

Code:

```
main = do
   putStrLn "Enter any number : "
   num <- getLine
   putStrLn ("number is "++num)
```

Output:

```
F17BCSE206>main
Enter any number : 
5
number is 5
:: IO ()
```

But my mind can't satisfies to input an integer we use getLine. Is there any other more precise way to input an integer and float using input output instead of     `func :: Int -> Int`

Can getInt or getFloat exists in haskell to input an integer or float?

Can anybody knows, So please help me.

Comment: The variable `num` in your code is a string that happens to contain the ascii character `5`.  If you wish to read a line then parse that line into another value, such as an integer, then consider using `read` or `readMaybe`.  More complex tasks arguably should be handled with a parser library such as parsec, megaparsec, or attoparsec.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a function `getNum` which is identical to `readLn`, but is restricted to types with a `Num` instance.

```
getNum :: (Read a, Num a, Show a) => IO a
getNum = readLn

main = do
  putStrLn "Enter any number: "
  num <- getNum
  -- or just inline the type annotation:
  -- num <- (readLn :: (Read a, Num a, Show a) => IO a)
  putStrLn ("number is " ++ show num)
```

The `Show` constraint is just to ease creating a string for the last `putStrLn`; it has nothing to do with parsing the input.

`getNum` will raise an error if `readLn` cannot parse the input string as a number, so this is probably the least good way to do this, but it is simple.

Comment: Can number be display without show? If not then why?

Comment: Sure; I just threw `show` in as a quick way to get this example to type-check. I guess for completeness, I should add that as a constraint to `getNum`.